# Is it safe to embed Twitter/Facebook API Key and Consumer Secret in Android/iOS code/pref file?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, twitter

I have Android and iOS apps which need to post to social networks, like Twitter and Facebook, directly using users' accounts.

Is it safe to embed the API Key and Consumer Secret in source code (or put in a pref file) within the Android/iOS app? Wouldn't it be possible that some hacker can find the API Key and Consumer Secret?

Answer (score 0):

Pref is never safe for storing your passwords, it have been seen simply in root devices you can encrypt your pass and then put in pref but still your encrypt key exist in code in my experience your codes are not safe too even you use ProGuard.it can decompile and normal developer(not even hacker) can find keys I suggest you never store passwords locally .

if you have to do this I suggest you

use complex code with multipart password that each part store in different location with encryption

also from `api 23+` you can use `KeyStore`

use ndk and store pass in `c` form

and finally use Proguard and DexGuard.